# UITableView strange behavior

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uitableview, landscape

I'm programming a preferences panel with a UITableView which looks like this:
[image]

The first section consists in simple rows and the second section in rows with a UISwitch as a subview.

When I change to landscape and start scrolling, the tableview behaves in a strange way:
[image]

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
// Configure the cell
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Help";
    }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"About us";
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Send to a friend";
    }
}else if(indexPath.section == 1){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Show favs at launch";
        [cell addSubview:favoritesSwitch];
    }else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Open with Safari";
        [cell addSubview:browserSwitch];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Remember query";
        [cell addSubview:lastQuerySwitch];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 3){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Automatic keyboard";
        [cell addSubview:keyboardSwitch];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be happen because you are using the same cell identifier to access the table cell.

Try with

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

instead of.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

Comment: Thank you :D It worked! But, why my CellIdentifier was not working?

Comment: Just a note.  This is not correct.  You do not need a unique cell identifier for every cell.  This defeats the very reason for using a cell identifier.  Using a cell identifier allows the system to quickly recycle similar cells for faster performance.  What you should do is give cells identifiers based on their type.  In your case it would be much much better to give the same identifier to all cells and assign the switch to cell.accessoryView which you can access and change accordingly on reuse.  Martin Ullrich's answer is correct.

Comment: This surely not the way to do things. Either you make custom cell (  hide unhide view on the basis of its index path) or handle it like Martin Ullrich has suggested.

Answer (score 4):

you should do just the following:

Continue to **use the same CellIdentifier for all cells** (performance! if you create a new identifier for each cell it will work, but consume lots of memory). Using more than one Cell Identifier is only appropriate when your cells are fundamentally different, like different custom UITableViewCell-Subclasses.

**don't add your switches as subviews (!!!)**, use `cell.accessoryView = mySwitch` instead. if this cell should not have a switch, be sure to set `cell.accessoryView = nil` to clean up a cell for reuse. Using accessoryView for your Switches will handle all the layout work automatically.

when you set accessoryView to nil, you can continue to use accessoryType for your DetailDisclosure-Buttons when you reuse cells!

Answer (score 0):

The tableView is recycling the cells to which you've added your browserSwitch, lastQuerySwitch and keyboardSwitch. There's no point at which these get removed from the cell view. Add the following lines just after // configure the cell comment. I think that'll sort it.

```
  [browserSwitch removeFromSuperview];
  [lastQuerySwitch removeFromSuperview];
  [keyboardSwitch removeFromSuperview];
```